# Apache2 rewrite strange behaviours

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

For a newsletter I'm trying to make clean url's for the unsubscribe page

At first I was having this, but it wasn't working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/unsubscribe/(.*)$ /unsubscribe.php?email=$1 [NC,L]
```

Which is very strange in my opinion. So I tried some other methods and ended up with the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?unsubscribe/?(.*)$ /unsubscribe.php?email=$1 [NC,L]
```

This, in fact, is working. But it is giving very strange results.

The email parameter value is now:

> .php/test

It is driving me nuts because I don't see why it is behaving this way.

Is there anybody who has an idea on what is happening here and how to get it fixed?

I'd rather not end up string replacing the php, there is something wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

How are you my friend ? :)

Could you try this and let me know if it works? Let's figure this out!

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^unsubscribe/([^/.]+)/?$ unsubscribe.php?email=$1 [L]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried your rule, it's doing nothing at all. It seems like the forward slash is ignored or something. Very strange

Answer (score 1):

Your first Rule doesn't work, because the rule gets what's BEHIND the base in the URL. So if the URL is `/unsubscribe/my@email`, the `RewriteBase` (`/`) gets removed, and the `RewriteRule` will see `unsubscribe/my@email` without the leading /.

In your second rule, BOTH `/`-es  are made optional by the `?`. So `unsubscribe.php/test` will find the literal `unsubscribe`, and take everything behind it - `.php/test` - and put it in the email parameter. Guess you should use `/unsubscribe/test`, not `/unsubscribe.php/test` in your browser when testing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I did not use /unsubscribe.php/test in my browser, just /unsubscribe/test

I changed the htaccess and removed the RewriteBase and replaced the rule by just this:

RewriteRule ^/unsubscribe$  /unsubscribe.php?email=test [NC,L]

this isn't working either; just an empty parameter.

Comment: Leave the RewriteBase, but change your pattern `^/unsubs...` to `^unsubs...` (remove the leading slash). Just like WarriorTurtle suggested, but with `RewriteBase /` as well, like you had it in your first example.

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^unsubscribe$  unsubscribe.php?email=test

is not working, it seems like it ignores the slash or something

Answer (score 1):

This rule should work for you:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/?unsubscribe(?:/(.+))?$ /unsubscribe.php?email=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Problem was in your regex which was matching the pattern after first application and doing the rewrite twice.

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it worked out.

It seemed like MultiViews (whatever that may be) was enabled by default.

Adding:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

To the htaccess (or apache config) fixed the problem.